# Getting 200 response but not hitting controller store() mthod

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am switching a form in a blade file to a vue based form posting with axios. I get a 200 response but I don't hit my store() method in my controller. I was hitting it with the original blade form. So far the things Ive tried are manually adding the csrf token, changing headers to content-type multipart, changing the post data to a JSON string,  and changing the handleSubmit to trigger the form. None of which seem to have any effect.

My blade file which houses the vue form

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <create-post></create-post>
</div>

@endsection
```

The createPost.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
    <h4>create post</h4>
    <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit" action='/p' enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
        <section v-if='step == 1'>
            <template v-for="(image, index) in images">
                <image-uploader-field
                    v-if='image_count >= index + 1'
                    v-bind:field='image'
                    v-bind:index='index'>
                </image-uploader-field>
            </template>
            <button
                v-if='image_count < 5'
                @click.prevent='addImage'>Add Another Image
            </button>

        </section>
        <section v-if='step == 2'>
            <h3>Auction Components</h3>
            <div>
                <label>starting bid $
                    <input type="number" min=".00" step=".01" v-model='starting_bid' placeholder='00.00' />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>bid increment $
                    <input type="number" min=".00" step=".01" v-model='bid_increment' placeholder='00.00'/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                end time
                    <datetime format="MM-DD-YYYY h:i:s" width="300px" v-model="end_time" ></datetime>

            </div>
            <div>
                <label>BIN $
                    <input type="number" min=".00" step=".01" v-model='bin' placeholder='00.00'/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>snipe
                    <input type='checkbox' v-model='snipe'/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label v-if="snipe != false">snipe time
                    <input type="number" min="1" step="any" v-model='snipe_time' /> minutes
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>auto remove bids
                    <input type='checkbox' v-model='autoremove_bids'/>
                </label>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section v-if='step == 3'>
            <h3>Write Caption</h3>
            <textarea
                v-model='caption'
                placeholder='type your message'
                class='form-control form-control-large'
                rows="4"
                cols="50">
            </textarea>
        </section>

        <section v-if='step == 4'>
            <h3>Preview</h3>
            <h4 v-if='caption !=null'>profilename: {{caption}}</h4>
            <h4 v-if='starting_bid !=null'>Starting Bid: ${{starting_bid}}</h4>
            <h4 v-if='bid_increment !=null'>Bid Increment: ${{bid_increment}}</h4>
            <h4 v-if='end_time !=null'>Auction ends at: {{end_time}}</h4>
            <h4 v-if='bin !=null'>BIN: ${{bin}}</h4>
            <h4 v-if='snipe_time !=null'>Snipe rule in effect: {{snipe_time}} minutes</h4>
        </section>

        <button
            v-if='step !== 1'
            @click.prevent='prevStep'>Previous</button>
        <button
            v-if='step !== totalsteps'
            @click.prevent='nextStep'
            v-text='nextText'></button>
        <button
            v-if='step == totalsteps'
            type='submit'>Post</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
    img{
        max-height: 36px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    import datetime from 'vuejs-datetimepicker';
    export default {
        components: { datetime },

        data: function () {
            return{
                image_count:1,
                max_uploads:5,
                totalsteps:4,
                step:1,
                images:[
                    {image_path:"", image_filters:[],},
                    {image_path:"", image_filters:[],},
                    {image_path:"", image_filters:[],},
                    {image_path:"", image_filters:[],},
                    {image_path:"", image_filters:[],},
                ],
                caption:null,
                starting_bid:null,
                bid_increment:null,
                end_time:null,
                bin:null,
                snipe:false,
                snipe_time:null,
                autoremove_bids:false,
                csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),

            }
        },
        computed: {
            nextText(){
                if(this.step == 3){
                    return 'Preview'
                } else {
                    return 'Next'
                }
            }

        },
        methods: {
            nextStep: function()
            {
                this.step++;
            },
            prevStep: function()
            {
                this.step--;
            },
            addImage: function()
            {
                this.image_count++
            },
            handleSubmit: function()
            {
                const post_data = Object.entries(this._data);
                axios.post('/p', post_data)

                  .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                  })
                  .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
            },
            onFileChange(e) {
                let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
                if (!files.length)
                    return;
                this.createImage(files[0]);
            },
            createImage(file) {
                 let reader = new FileReader();
                 let vm = this;
                 reader.onload = (e) => {
                     vm.image = e.target.result;
                 };
                 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
             },

            editImage(){
                alert('render image-editor here');
            },

        },

    }
</script>
```

my route for the post in web.php

```
Route::get('/p/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store');
```

the store method in my postsController, I set a console.log just to see If I'm hitting it which it appears I am not

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts/create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        console.log('hit store method');
        //VALIDATES DATA
        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image1' => ['required', 'image',],
            'image2' => 'image',
            'image3' => 'image',
            'image4' => 'image',
            'image5' => 'image',
        ]);
        //CREATE IMAGES ARRAY AND UPLOADS TO S3
        $imageArray = [];
        $imageCount = 1;
        foreach($data as $key => $value){
            if (strpos($key, 'image') !== false) {
                $imagePath = request('image' . $imageCount)->store('uploads', 's3');
                $imageCount ++;
                array_push($imageArray, 'https://instagrizzle-development.s3.amazonaws.com/' . $imagePath);
            }
        }
        //Relational method HARDCODED profile
        auth()->user()->profiles[0]->posts()->create([
            'caption' => $data['caption'],
            'image' => json_encode($imageArray),
        ]);

        return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->profiles[0]->id);
    }
}
```

adding the

```
action='/p' enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
```

to the form tag seems redundant but I figured I would try it. Also not sure but does axios automatically add a csrf token by default? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

This is the response I get back after submitting the form
[response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jt9I.png)

Comment: why you have a `console.log('hit store method');` in your laravel controller?

Comment: Just to get some feedback that I am indeed hitting the store method

Comment: I had a dd(response()); before. But since I had .prevent on my submit button I was thinking I may not see it

Comment: replace it with `return 'ok' ;`. `console.log()` is javascript, it doesn't work in php

Comment: What you might try is an Log::info('') or dd() in your controllers constructor above the auth middleware

Comment: amazing thanks. I am infact getting 'ok' back. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean putting dd in the __construct() above where I call auth, or above that method completely?

Comment: Just to see if it hit's te controller... that like it., i edited, my original answer, i assume you need another middleware

auth instead auth:api in your controllers constructor

see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#protecting-routes

Comment: Now that you know the call is hiting the controller method, remove that `return 'ok';`. And in the `then` and `catch` methods of axios, type `console.log(response.data)` instead of just `console.log(response)` to see what response you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace it with return 'ok' ;. console.log() is javascript, it doesn't work in php – porloscerros Ψ Nov 28 at 23:37

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the wrong midleware

auth instead auth:api in your controllers constructor

see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#protecting-routes

You also probably miss some headers in your axios calls, you could verify in

your browser if they are all there.

Also verify your DOM for the csrf-token

Then you could use a wrapper Axios object to set your default headers.

like this. (Save it for example to api.js)

```
import Axios from 'axios'

export default() => {
  return Axios.create({
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
    }
  })
}
```

Then import the axios your vue component..

```
import Api from './api';
```

And you can use it then like an axios object

```
Api().request()
```

Or if you will use this single way of authentication through all your axios calls. You just do it the same way as laravel starts out in their bootstrap file

Like this:

```
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```